# Best way to automatically email user when web application is only 1/2 way complete

Tags: web-applications

My web application functions like an employment application. There are about 5 screens, and the first screen captures username and email address. Assuming user gets passed first screen (we have now an email), I want to figure out two things

1) on what screen the user drops out (nice to have, but not priority)
2) Most importantly, how to email a reminder after a certain amount of time that the user has an incomplete application pending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would write a record in a database with the user's information and a date stamp.  Periodically, you will query the database for any records that are over a set amount of time. This will give you all the users that have not finished for more than your required time and you can email them.

You can also write to this record each time they advance to a new screen.  That way you can know where they stopped.